# Changing posts scheme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, plugins

How can I changing posts scheme in wordpress ?

Do I need to use for this plugin?

e.g : [here](http://prntscr.com/4w45lq) - posts scheme on home page

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but will try to answer it.

If you want to change the way your posts *look*, you can do one of these methods:

1) Use a different theme. Download and install new theme, then activate it.

2) Use custom CSS. Some themes support adding custom CSS. If your theme does not support it, you can make a Child Theme and edit the "style.css" file.

Comment: I think I can do it for help with php.  I mean:

Estimate e.g 4 posts will have normal size and rest have half of normal size but i have small problem - I don't know how ;(